# Error due to missing parent.contents in some webpages

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape information from a site, but I am getting an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent'
```

Could you please tell me how to skip this error and keep collecting data?
The code I have been using is

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import pandas as pd


def main(req, num):
    r = req.get(web+"/page/{}/".format(num))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    for article in soup.select('article.border_top'):
        print(article.select_one('span.homepage_post-date').text)
        print(article.select_one('h1.homepage_post_title').text)
        print(article.select_one('p').text)
        try:
            print(article.select_one("a.read-more").parent.contents[0])# this seems causing the issue
        except:
            print(num)
    return article.select_one('span.homepage_post-date').text, article.select_one('h1.homepage_post_title').text, article.select_one('p').text, article.select_one("a.read-more").parent.contents[0]  # this seems causing the issue


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=30) as executor:
    with requests.Session() as req:
        fs = [executor.submit(main, req, num) for num in range(1, 128)] # this sets the range of pages
        allin = []
        for f in fs:
            allin.append(f.result())
```

Comment: Please share the URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should access parent node in try block, just assign value here, if the node is missing, set default val:

```
parent_content = None
try:
    parent_content = article.select_one("a.read-more").parent.contents[0])
except:
    parent_content = 'some default value'
```

More generally, you should use try ... except in the top layer of loop, any Error should be catched and print the message but not to interrupt the iteration, that's a practical trick for crawl from my side